# Is it possible to export/import type definitions in Hopper

Tags: hopper

Can I export my type definitions from one Hopper project and import them to another? I would like to define the data types used for a target just once, then export/import them when reversing new versions of the same target.

I've searched many variations of this without much luck, checked the user interface, and the scripting documentation (if I can access the types from Python I can write my own export/import).

Answer (score 1):

As of version 4.3.12 you can import/export types to/from a Hopper project.